# Django Model Into Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model with name field:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max-length=50)
```

I want to build a dictionary of all categories with the name as key and instance as value.

Is there a simpler way than?

```
category_map = {name: instance for (name, instance)
                in [(c.name, c) for c in Category.objects.all()]}
```

I know there is in_bulk API in Django:

```
category_map = Category.objects.in_bulk()
```

However it uses primary key and I don't see a way to use different field instead.

I'm using Django 1.6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second `for` loop:

```
category_map = {c.name: c for c in Category.objects.all()}
```