# Filter django model using Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, django, django-models, dictionary-comprehension

I have a model, called cards, which contains a number of elements I want to loop through. So I was trying to use some dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
cards = Card.objects.filter(device=device)
output = { c.id : [c.generateData(), c.sensor.getLatestTime()] for c in cards}
```

While running that code, it breaks on the output statement with the following error:

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result
> using slicing.

Most of the pre-existing answers I found for that exact error were for cases where the queryset is being confused with a single field, as in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284938/how-to-fix-the-queryset-value-for-an-exact-lookup-must-be-limited-to-one-result), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67702924/valueerror-at-checkout-the-queryset-value-for-an-exact-lookup-must-be-limited). However in my case, I am expecting, and handling it as a queryset by looping through it.

I have also seen a question that is similar in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829583/django-model-into-dictionary-comprehension) about using dictionary comprehension on the models, however as far as I can see, my format is almost the same (Unless the list as a second parameter is causing an issue somehow?)

**Edit:** I noticed while trying to test where the error is occuring, that even a simple for-loop such as:

`for card in cards:`

is giving the same error, the error seems to be somehow in the line:

`cards = Card.objects.filter(device=device)`

Which honestly isn't making much sense to me. It feels as if I am forgetting something fundemental but I can't see it yet.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've shown. The full traceback would be very helpful, as well as the Card class definition of device, and how you're getting the device value you're passing to filter...

Comment: Just after an hour of troubleshooting before sending the question, and 30 minutes after posting it I figured it out. Thanks for the help however. It always seems the most annoying problems are the simplest afterall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the error was very dumb, in the statement:

```
output = { c.id : [c.generateData(), c.sensor.getLatestTime()] for c in cards}
```

The error was occuring around here, causing me to think that the issue occured at:

```
cards = Card.objects.filter(device=device)
```

Since the code broke around that part, however, looking further into it, since replacing this statement with:

```
cards = Card.objects.all()
```

Solved the issue, I found out that the error was occurring on the filter parameters, since I was doing the following a few lines earlier:

```
device = Device.objects.filter(project__user=user,id=id)
```

thus, tried to use a query-set in the 2nd condition. Thus replacing it with:

```
device = Device.objects.get(project__user=user,id=id)
```

resolved my issue.